# Numpy.loadtext cannot read own arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

So I'm trying to make a demo for a class.  I have some raw data in a csv file, I open it using numpy.loadtext, I smooth it, I save it using numpy.savetext

Then, in a new program, I try to open the file using numpy.loadtext, and the first column, which should be 0, 0.083333333... in 0.08333333 increments comes out as 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1....?  The other column is totally fine, but row 0 just imports incorrectly.  Yet it's FINE at all stages of the program before.

I read in with:

```
testfile=numpy.loadtxt(open("rawGecko.csv","rb"),delimiter=",")
```

Then stuff happens to generate an array fout
Then I save:

```
numpy.savetxt("SMgecko.csv",fout,fmt='%.6f',delimiter=",")
```

New program, I open with

```
testfile=numpy.loadtxt('SMgecko.csv',delimiter=",")
```

And the first row is just 0 followed by all 1's

Can numpy really not read the files it generates?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Ok, I've uploaded the offending file to my dropbox:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/c4wk9kn2f35ksgw/SMgecko.csv?dl=0

Comment: Ok, so closing and opening Anaconda apparently fixed it.  No idea why.

Comment: Ok, some students are still having this problem.  Apparently, if you open a file, then set a variable as equal to a subset of that file, Python will actually change the file when you change the variable.  WTF?